# Communications Security

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications

To secure a communication, quantum cryptography can be used. The principle is to use an optical channel which allows the emission of photons in 2 simultaneous states and a radio channel which makes it possible to find the encryption key.

Here is my question: Why isn't a radio channel used to transmit the encryption key? For example, one could use waveforms which would be in several states at the same time as for the optical channel.

Comment: Can you give an example of a waveform that is in several states at the same time? Maybe a sketch, or an equation that shows the multiple simultaneous states occurring simultaneously?

Comment: @DilipSarwate it's not a waveform. the literal photon emitted by the transmitter is in a quantum state.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am simply repeating the words used by the OP when he says “waveform”. I don’t see any photons in it.

Answer (score 1):

> waveforms which would be in several states at the same time as for the optical channel.

I'd be excited to hear that! So far, physicist have not been able to do that over a channel so disturbed as the wireless channel that you can statistically preserve quantum states over it but are still emitting with a power low enough so that state readout without destruction is impossible (and that's where the quantum "secrecy" comes from). Remember, your quantum is typically a single photon. That's not much energy for a wireless channel!

So, your premise is wrong. You'll need to look deeper on how the quantum key distribution actually works, on a physical level.